# Handling pass by reference of a character array in C

Tags: c, string

I want to change the value of character array, when I am using like this

```
char *str;
fun(str);

void fun(char *str) {
    str = (char *) ("changed");
}
```

It is not doing anything and having str as null

whereas in this manner

```
char *str;
fun(&str);

void fun(char **str) {
    *str = (char **) ("changed");
}
```

It is coming fine.
But I have a restriction to have the function definition as void fun(char *str), how to change the value using this usecase

Comment: `*str = (char **) ("changed");` is wrong, don't cast a `char *` with `(char **)`, the first snippet is also wrong, you are changing the value of a local variable. _how to change the value using this usecase_: Using `strcpy`: `void fun(char *str) { strcpy(str, "changed);  }` . `str` must point to allocated space (an array or via `malloc`) with space enough to store "changed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to change the value of character array

With `fun(char *str)`, `str` is a pointer.  To change the value of the *character array*, do not change the pointer `str`.  Change the contents of the memory `str` points to.

```
void fun(char *str) {
    // str = (char *) ("changed");
    str[0] = 'c';
    str[1] = 'h';
    str[2] = 'a';
    str[3] = 'n';
    str[4] = 'g';
    str[5] = 'e';
    str[6] = 'd';
    str[7] = '\0';
    // or simply 
    strcpy(str, "changed");
}
```

Be sure when calling that the pointer references available space

```
char buffer[100] = "Before";
printf("<%s>\n", buffer);
fun(buffer);
printf("<%s>\n", buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual use case is that you have an *array* that you pass to the function.  Under most circumstances, an expression of array type will be converted (or "decay") to an expression of pointer type, and the value of the pointer will be the address of the first element of the array.  Example:

```
#define SOME_SIZE 20   // Size of the longest string you intend to store; 20 is just an example

void fun( char *str )
{
  strncpy( str, "changed", SOME_SIZE );
  str[SOME_SIZE] = 0; // make sure string is terminated if SOME_SIZE <= strlen("changed")        
}

int main( void )
{
  char buf[SOME_SIZE+1] = "foo"; // +1 for 0 terminator
  printf( "buf before fun - %s\n", str );
  fun( buf );
  printf( "buf after fun - %s\n", str );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You're not changing the value of `str` itself, you're changing the contents of the buffer that `str` *points to*.

Comment: Concerning _strings_ like `"changed"`, I find _length_ as 7 and _size_ as 8 clear.  Using `SOME_SIZE` as the maximum _length_ of a string in `buf[]` not so clear.   Perhasp `SOME_LENGTH`?